# how to include a header file in another header file

Tags: include-path

I have 2 header files with their path being defined as below.

```
folder1/subfolder1/subfolder2/headerfile1
folder1/subfolder3/subfolder4/headerfile2
```

Now I want to include headerfile2 in headerfile1, so included the following code in headerfile1.

```
#include “subfolder3/subfolder4/headerfile2.h”
```

But I am getting error as directory/file not found. 
I am not understanding where I am going wrong.

Comment: And your programming language is? Maybe C?

Answer (score 0):

1. You have irregular quotes in your `#include` directive; use standard `"` quotes.
2. You may have to specify to your compiler where it should look for the include path, e. g. many compilers have an option `-I` for this, so it would be `-Ifolder1`, provided the current directory contains `folder1`, or `folder1` is an absolute path.